# For loop only printing first iteration multiple time

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am building a rent calculator app which have 3 fields total rent,rent incresese per year and number of years to calculate rent for .when i fill the input field the code only print first iteration multiple time i want it to print  increased value with years

Html file

Rent Calculator

```
<input type="number" name="rent" placeholder="Enter your total rent" [(ngModel)]="rent" />

<input type="number" placeholder="Rent increase per Year" [(ngModel)]="increase">

<input type="number" placeholder="Number of Total Years" [(ngModel)]="months">

<button type="button" (click)="calculate()"> Calculate </button>
<br>

<h4 *ngFor="let r of total;let i=index">

    Year {{i+1}}&nbsp; &nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp;{{r}}&nbsp;Rs

</h4>
```

ts file...

```js
export class RentCalculatorComponent {

  constructor() { }

  increase!: number;

  months!: number;

  rent!: number;

  new!: number;

  total: any[] = [];//declare an array

  calculate() {

    for (let i = 0; i <= this.months - 1; i++) {
     
      this.new = this.rent + this.rent * this.increase / 100;

      this.total[i] = this.new.toFixed(2);; //here store in the array the result

      console.log(this.total[i]);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your output doesn't depend on the index, you can replace `this.total[i] =` with `let foo =` without changing the logic, thus the output. In other words, you are printing many different lines, but they all contain the same value

Comment: Maybe you meant to do `this.new += `?

Comment: if i do this.rent =  instead of this.new = then it works but i dont want it that way beacuse it also update  rent input field

Comment: i  want for loop to run logic on new value of this.rent that come from first iteration not on entered value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing an array of length 0. When you are looping from 0 to `month.length - 1` you are basically setting values out of bounds of your array. You should try to use `this.total.push(this.new.toFixed(2));` to increase the length of your array.

Nevertheless a couple of hints:

- You should not name variables `new`, since this is a reserved word in many languages
- you should not use the "bang-operator" (or "non-null-assertion-operator") when the variable is indeed not set. You should just initialize it with a valid value in your case

Comment: Don't abuse `any` type. If array `total` is designed to contain strings, then it should be declared as string[]. Or, even better, store numbers in array and use DecimalPipe in component to output formatted values.

Comment: thank you for the hint @edmunds Folkmanis! You are right. And of course it is printing the same value multiple times. Your calculation (`this.new = this.rent + this.rent * this.increase / 100;`) is not based on your variable `i`.

Comment: didnot work printing first iteration result multiple time